# AS3 Accessing classes and variables

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class

I am new to AS3 and I try to make a simple flash game.
My problem concerns accessing a specific array outside of its class.
I succeeded accessing some variables and function but I am quite stuck on this one.

There are 3 classes : Game which is the main class tied to the flash file, Level1 which spawn background element and enemies, and finally the Enemy class.

The Game class instantiate the Level1 class which spawn enemies (with Enemy class) and push them to an array.
When the enemy get hit, a method in the Enemy class remove it from the display list and then tries to remove it from the array located in the Level1 Class, wich fails and throw :

1119: Access of possibly undefined property level1 through a reference with static type Class.

Another problem is some time the bullets stop in the middle of screen, I havn't been able to track down this bug as well.

Any way, this is my first code related post and if it's too messy, tell me and I'll try to make it more readable.
Sorry for any inconveniance and thank you for your help
-Yaniv

```
 package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class Game extends MovieClip
    {
        public var player:Player;
        public var level1:Level1;
        public var bullet:Bullet;
        private var bullets_arr:Array;
        var fire_on : Boolean;
        var fire_counter : int;

        public function Game()
        {
            level1=new Level1(this.stage);

            player = new Player  ;
            addChild(player);
            player.y = 600;
            bullets_arr = [];
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Main);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mouseDownHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,mouseUpHandler);
        }

        function mouseDownHandler($e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            fire_on = true;
        }

        function mouseUpHandler($e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            fire_on = false;
            fire_counter = 0;
        }

        function fire():void
        {
            bullet = new Bullet  ;
            addChild(bullet);
            bullet.x = player.x;
            bullet.y = player.y - 32;
            bullets_arr.push(bullet);
        }

        public function Main(e: Event):void
        {
            player.x = mouseX;

            if (bullets_arr)
            {
                for (var m:int = 0; m < bullets_arr.length; m++)
                {
                    bullets_arr[m].y -=  20;

                    if(level1.enemies_arr)
                    {   
                        for (var n:int = 0; n < level1.enemies_arr.length; n++)
                        {
                            if (bullets_arr[m])
                            {
                                if (level1.enemies_arr[n])
                                {
                                    if (level1.enemies_arr[n].hitTestObject(bullets_arr[m]))
                                    {
                                        if(bullets_arr[m].parent)
                                        {
                                            bullets_arr[m].parent.removeChild(bullets_arr[m]);
                                            bullets_arr.splice(bullets_arr[m],1);
                                            level1.enemies_arr[n].DoDamage(10);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(fire_on)
            {
                fire_counter++;
                if(fire_counter == 01)
                {

                    fire();
                }
                else if(fire_counter >5)
                {
                    fire_counter =0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}




package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Level1 extends MovieClip{

        var i:int;
        var j:int;
        var frame :int;
        public var enemy:Enemy;
        public var enemies_arr:Array;


        public function Level1(target:Stage) 
        {
            frame = 0;
            enemies_arr = [];

            for (var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (var j:int = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    enemy = new Enemy;
                    enemy.x = j*100 + 260;
                    enemy.y = i*40 - 150;
                    target.addChild(enemy);
                    enemies_arr.push(enemy);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Enemy extends MovieClip
    {

        var Health : int;
        var splash:Splash;

        function Enemy()
        {
            Health =30;
        }
        public function DoDamage(Damage:int)
        {
            Health -= Damage;
            if (Health <= 0)
            {
                Die();
            }
        }
        public function Die()
        {
            if(this.parent)
            {
                this.parent.removeChild(this);

                //HERE IS THE ERROR
                Game.level1.enemies_arr.splice(this,1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell us which line is causing the error? It saves us time having to search for the specific line. Sorry, after searching your code I saw the comment for the error...

Comment: I am glad you finally find it. Is there a way to separate the 3 chunk of code so it will be easier to read? I don't seee the line number how to diplay it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntacitical problem you're running into is that you're trying to get level1 from the class Game, when level1 is an instance variable, not a static variable.  As an instance variable, level1 is a completely different variable for each instance of game, so if you simply say `Game.level1`, the compiler wonders, "Which Game?"

To change this, you could simply change level1 into a static variable, by changing this:

```
public var level1:Level1;
```

to this:

```
public static var level1:Level1;
```

That way the variable would be the same across all instances, and you shouldn't have any trouble accessing it on this line:

```
Game.level1.enemies_arr.splice(this,1);
```

I will say though that there could be issues here with certain design principles (it may be that you should use callbacks or signals or something for modularity), but the quick-and-easy fix is to just add the word `static` to level1's declaration.

Comment: it seems too work but the behaviors seems to be strange now.After I kill 1 or 2 enemies I can't kill more.Like if an object was blocking the bullet. I'll run some test and upload the game if I can't find a solution. Thanks any way

Comment: is it possible that I got a duplicate enemy object that is not on the display list and blocking my bullet object ?

Comment: I'm not sure...I haven't used splice with an object reference before, so I tried running a real quick experiment to see if that might've been failing to remove the reference from the array, but it doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 1):

You should call level1 on the Game instance.

In a simple way, you could define the Game as Singleton

```
public class Game extends MovieClip {

   private static var _instance:Game;

   public static function getInstance():Game {

      if (_instance == null) {

           _instance = new Game();
      }

      return _instance ;

   }
}
```

So the Die function will be like this

```
   public function Die()
    {
        if(this.parent)
        {
            this.parent.removeChild(this);

            //HERE IS THE ERROR
            Game.getInstance().level1.enemies_arr.splice(this,1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's weird, it throws 1120: Access of undefined property _instance. despite the variable declaration.

Comment: _instance should be declared as static. I have  edit the answer

Comment: this seems to work as well but just like Panzercrisis answers, I have now a weird behaviours, might be related to my code. I need to dig deeper. Thanks for your help, I need to dig all these concepts.